Quicksight KPI from LAC-A calculated fields
I have the below table in Quicksight and I want to create a KPI where I will find the percentage of (F_Amount - P_Amount) / P_Amount  but only for the IDs that F_amount is > 0.
So in the below example the KPI would be (15829.72 - 15561.17) / 15829.72
where 15829.72 = 12997.52 + 112.2 + 2720 and 15561.17 = 12766.45 + 110.72 + 2684 from the ID 58072
And everything regarding ID 65065 will be omitted as this ID doesn't have values in F_Amount.
P_Amount and F_Amount are calculated fields as below.
P_Amount = avg({P_Amount USD}, [{EX_ID}])
F_Amount = avg({F_Amount USD}, [{EX_ID}])




ID
PR_ID
EX_ID
P_Amount
F_Amount




65065
56279
726170
4351.26



65065
56279
726172
33430.77



65065
56279
726180
1143



58072
49947
646167
12997.52



58072
49947
646168
112.2



58072
49947
646169
2720



58072
53303
687054

12766.45


58072
53303
687055

110.72


58072
53303
687056

2684



